# How to turn on and start openstack and openvswitch on a single machine?

Tags: openstack

I have a 32-bit version of Ubuntu 13.04 running in my desktop. 
My intention is to turn ON and start both openstack and openVswitch in my desktop, such that I could get some practical experiment out of operating the twos. I just do NOT know how to turn them ON and configure them, could you please provide me with pointers to articles, which explain how these are supposed to be done CORRECTLY?

Answer (score 3):

Just for playing with openstack, take a look at DevStack.  It's a nice way to start up everything and play around. Not sure if you need to be running 64 bit mode though. Need to have machine that supports virtualization.

There are several automated provisioning packages out there for OpenStack, Ubuntu has one with Juju, Vagrant (has a devstack box), and many more, but for just starting it on one machine to learn more about it devstack is nice, IMHO.

Ref: http://devstack.org/

Answer (score 2):

OpenStack is not normally deployed on only a single machine. You can use the [`virtual-maas`](http://jujucharms.com/~virtual-maasers/precise/virtual-maas) Juju charm to deploy something that can be used to provide enough virtual machines to run OpenStack services.

The nested VMs will be slower than "native OpenStack", of course, but if you don't have half-dozen or more actual machines to use for testing OpenStack, this is a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

If you install Openstack via the installer:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack

It provides you with an option to do a **Single** install. What this option does is deploy all openstack services on a single machine **with** a single network device. The single install path utilizes KVM, LXC, and OVS to accomplish this.

This is also perfect for a single machine as the entire deployment is done within a single container.